# .cocos-project.json not found when building for Android platform

Tags: android, json, cocos2d-x

When I ran the command `cocos run -s ~/MyCompany/MyGame/ -p android`
I got the following error: `/Users/me/MyCompany/MyGame/.cocos-project.json is not found`

I double checked that the file exists yet it says it’s missing. I’m using Mac OSX El Capitain and Cocos2d-x version 3.12.